# Value isn't changing from 12

Tags: python

I cant seem to be able to change fprice from being the same as the input and isnt * with VAT

```
while True:
    VAT=1
   
    shoep = int(input("what is the price of the shoe (in euros)"))
    country = input("what country are you buying the shoe from ")
    

    if country == "Germany":
        VAT=int(1.19)

    elif country =="France":
        VAT=int(1.20)

    elif country == "Spain":
        VAT=int(1.21)

    elif country == "Italy":
        VAT=int(1.22)

    elif country == "Portugal":
        VAT=int(1.23)
    elif country != "Germany" or "Portugal" or "Italy" or "Spain"or "France" :
        print("invalid input please try again")
    fprice=shoep*VAT
    fprice=float(fprice)
    float(shoep)
    float(VAT)
    
    
    print("the price of the shoe is €",fprice)
```

Comment: Well, what are your inputs?

Comment: Why are you casting the VATs to `int`? You lose the decimal precision this way. `int(1.2) --> 1`, but `int(1.99999) --> 1` as well. You'll always multiply by one.

Comment: `elif country != "Germany" or "Portugal" or "Italy" or "Spain"or "France" ` doesn't mean what you think it means. That condition is *always* False. It *doesn't* mean `elif country != "Germany" or country != "Portugal" ...' etc.

Comment: @JohnColeman - The last condition is always *True*. So it kind of does what it should by pure chance.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny You are right. I forgot precedence at first.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
 VAT=int(1.19)
```

Will cause the value of `VAT` to be `1`, since `1` is the floor value. When you cast to `int` it will take the floor of whatever you give it.

```
>>> int(1.9)
1
>>> int(1.12)
1
>>> int(2.1)
2
```

One times anything, by the identity property, will be that thing. So a `12` input will result in a `12` output.

I think you want:

```
 VAT=1.19
```

You also have some logic that is weird around trying to handle any countries not in your list. On the first blush, you might simply use `else`. However, you don't again ask for the country input and will therefore output an invalid (times 1, the default value of VAT, result). A structure like this will likely serve you better:

```
from typing import Dict, Optional

taxes = {
  "Germany": 1.19,
  "France": 1.20,
  "Spain": 1.21,
  "Italy": 1.22,
  "Portugal": 1.23,
}

def get_vat(taxes: Dict[str, float], msg: Optional[str] = None) -> float:
    if msg is not None:
        print(msg)
    country = input("What country are you buying the shoe from?")
    # Use the `get` functions ability to define a default to ask until the users get it right.
    return taxes.get(country, get_vat(taxes, "You've selected an invalid country. Try again!")
        
while True:
    shoe_price = float(input("what is the price of the shoe (in euros)")  # You could use an int, but you're dropping info.
    vat = get_vat(taxes)
    fprice: float = shoe_price * vat  # This will naturally be a float, no need to cast.
    print("the price of the shoe is €",fprice)
```

Answer (score 2):

> cant seem to be able to change fprice from being the same as the input

`int(1.<<anything>>)` is always `1`, so you are multiplying your input by 1, and getting the same value

Solution: remove `int()` function usage.

You should also [`import decimal`, and use this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), as it is more suitable for currency precision

---

Unrelated, the "invalid input" condition is incorrect. If you want to check mulitple values, use `in`

```
elif country not in ["Germany", "Portugal", "Italy", "Spain", "France"]:
    print("invalid input please try again")
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things to Note:
Firstly,
`VAT = int(1.22)`
This coverts the value `1.22` into the integer `1`. Therefore, no matter the country, VAT will always be 1.
You can just say `VAT = 1.22` (for example)

Secondly, the condition

```py
elif country != "Germany" or "Portugal" or "Italy" or "Spain" or "France"
```

isn't doing what you think it does.

```py
elif country != "Germany" or country != "Portugal" or country != "Italy" or ...
```

is the correct method.
Another way:

```py
elif country not in ["Germany", "Portugal", "Italy", ...]:
    print("invalid input please try agaim")
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is not changing from 12, because when you type a floating point number with `int`, it would convert it to a whole number, i.e. `int(1.19)` is `1`.

Also, the statement `elif country != "Germany" or "Portugal" or "Italy" or "Spain"or "France":` will give you a runtime error, and instead a simple `else` statement would do the job.

Moreover, the statements `float(shoep)` and `float(VAT)` seems to do nothing, and can be completely removed.

So I would rewrite the code as follows to make it work.

```
while True:
    
    VAT=1
   
    shoep = int(input("what is the price of the shoe (in euros)"))
    country = input("what country are you buying the shoe from ")
    
    if country == "Germany":
        VAT = 1.19
    elif country =="France":
        VAT = 1.20
    elif country == "Spain":
        VAT = 1.21
    elif country == "Italy":
        VAT = 1.22
    elif country == "Portugal":
        VAT = 1.23
    else:
        print("invalid input please try again")

    fprice=float(shoep*VAT)
    print("the price of the shoe is €",fprice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you want to achieve, using a dictionary to map country to VAT rate makes the code more compact and readable:

```
import decimal as d

try_again = True
VAT_by_country = {"Germany": d.Decimal('1.19'), "France": d.Decimal('1.2'), "Spain": d.Decimal('1.21'), \
"Italy": d.Decimal('1.22'), "Portugal": d.Decimal('1.22')}

while try_again:
   shoep = int(input("what is the price of the shoe (in euros)"))
   country = input("what country are you buying the shoe from ")

   VAT = VAT_by_country.get(country, 1)
   if VAT > 1:
      try_again = False
      fprice=float(shoep*VAT)
      print("the price of the shoe is €",fprice)
   else:
      print("invalid input please try again")
```